Nothing is being saved at local storage
I started writing JS code 3 weeks ago and currently I am trying to build  a game-however for the past  couple of days  ran into a problem concerning the way I use local storage- basically the data is not being displayed on a page refresh-it is not being saved- here is the relevant part of my js file. One final thing that i wanted to add is that the browser also gives me the feedback that objectForMonsterMarkers.push is not a function - I tried to fix it, but I could not.
let playerCharachteristics = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('playerCharachteristics'));
let monsterCharachteritics = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('monsterCharachteritics'));
let objectForMonsterMarkers = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('monsterBooleanImage'));

if (objectForMonsterMarkers === null) {
  objectForMonsterMarkers = [];
};

if (playerCharachteristics || monsterCharachteritics === null) {

  playerCharachteristics = {
    pStrength: parseInt(Math.random() * 80), //stands for attack points, which are then increased in monsterhit 
    pStrengthBar: parseInt(Math.random() * 80),
    pDefence: parseInt(Math.random() * 70),
    pDefenceBar: parseInt(Math.random() * 80),
    pHealth: parseInt(Math.random() * 100),
    pHealthBar: true
  };

  monsterCharachteritics = {
    mStrength: 40,
    mStrengthBar: true,
    mDefence: parseInt(Math.random() * 80),
    mDefenceBar: parseInt(Math.random() * 80),
    mHealth: parseInt(Math.random() * 110),
    mHealthBar: parseInt(Math.random() * 80)
  };
} else if (playerCharachteristics || monsterCharachteritics === null) {
  generateMonster(objectForMonsterMarkers);
}

function generateMonster(monsterBooleanImage) {

  let monsterHealthAdditionalHealthPoints = 800;

  console.log(monsterCharachteritics.mHealth);

  if (monsterBooleanImage === true) {
    console.log(monsterBooleanImage);
    divImage.innerHTML += `
          <img alt="" class="first" fetchpriority="auto" loading="auto"
                  src="https://i.pinimg.com/564x/85/c8/f3/85c8f3eca9a5cbdef756956ba16b89dd.jpg" 
                  id="gameCanvas" width="270" height="330" >
          `
    monsterHealthDiv.innerHTML += `
            <div id="monsterhealthbar"> 
                <div class="monsterhealthfill" > 
                    <i class="hp3"> Monster Health
                    </i>
                </div>
            </div> 
            <div id="monsterstrengthbar"> 
            <div class="monsterstrengthfill" > 
                <i class="hp3"> Monster Strength
                </i>
            </div>
        </div> 
        `
    monsterSDFbarFills.mhFill = document.querySelector(".monsterhealthfill");
    monsterCharachteritics.mHealthBar = document.querySelector("#monsterhealthbar");
    monsterCharachteritics.mStrengthBar = document.querySelector("#monsterstrengthbar")
    monsterSDFbarFills.msFill = document.querySelector(".monsterstrengthfill");
    monsterCharachteritics.mHealth += monsterHealthAdditionalHealthPoints;
    //monsterCharachteritics.mHealthBar= monsterHealthBar;

    monsterCharachteritics.mHealthBar.style.width = monsterCharachteritics.mHealth + 'px';
    monsterCharachteritics.mStrength = 35; //that is base monster strength
    monsterSDFbarFills.mhFill.innerHTML = `
                <i class="hp3"> Monster Health Points -${monsterCharachteritics.mHealth}</i>
                `;
    monsterSDFbarFills.msFill.innerHTML = `
                <i class="hp3"> Monster Strength Points -${monsterCharachteritics.mStrength}</i>
                `;
    checker2++;
    if (checker2 === 1) {
      divThrowButon.innerHTML = `
             <button onclick="throwForStrengthHealth()"> Throw For Health and Base Strength</button> 
             `;
    }
    console.log(monsterBooleanImage);

    // \<div id="deletebutton"\> bezshe v divthrowbuton
    attackDiv.innerHTML = `        <button class="button"  onclick="monsterHit(${monsterBooleanImage})">Attack</button>        `;
    // moveButton.innerHTML=\`\`;
    console.log(monsterBooleanImage);

    localStorage.setItem('monsterBooleanImage', JSON.stringify(monsterBooleanImage));
    localStorage.setItem('playerCharachteristics', JSON.stringify(playerCharachteristics));
    localStorage.setItem('monsterCharachteritics', JSON.stringify(monsterCharachteritics));

  }

}

function monsterHit(booleanGameMechanics) {
  console.log(booleanGameMechanics);
  let playerThrowAdditionalAttackPoints = parseInt(Math.random() * 80);
  let overallPlayerDamage = playerCharachteristics.pStrength + playerThrowAdditionalAttackPoints;
  let monsterThrowAdditionalAttackPoints = parseInt(Math.random() * 90);
  let overallMonsterDamage = monsterThrowAdditionalAttackPoints + monsterCharachteritics.mStrength;

  if (booleanGameMechanics === true) {
    console.log(booleanGameMechanics + 'isTrue');
    if (overallMonsterDamage > overallPlayerDamage) {
      attackExchangeCounter++
    }
    if (attackExchangeCounter >= 3) {
      attackDiv.innerHTML = `
                         `;
      attackDiv.innerHTML = `
                         <button onclick="secondAttack(${overallMonsterDamage},${booleanGameMechanics})"> Second Attack</button>
                         <button onclick="lowerYourAttackPoints(${booleanGameMechanics})"> Lower your attack points</button>
                         `
      attackExchangeCounter = 0;
    }
    playerCharachteristics.pHealth -= overallMonsterDamage;
    console.log(playerCharachteristics.pHealth);
    monsterCharachteritics.mHealth -= overallPlayerDamage;

    if (overallMonsterDamage > 50) {
      objectHealthWidth.widthForHealth -= 50;
    } else if (overallMonsterDamage > 100) {
      objectHealthWidth.widthForHealth -= 100;
    } else {
      objectHealthWidth.widthForHealth -= 20
    }
    console.log(playerCharachteristics.pHealthBar);
    console.log(playerCharachteristics.pHealthBar.style.width);
    playerCharachteristics.pHealthBar.style.width = objectHealthWidth.widthForHealth + "px";
    monsterCharachteritics.mHealthBar.style.width = monsterCharachteritics.mHealth + "px";

    console.log(playerCharachteristics.pHealthBar);
    console.log(playerCharachteristics.pHealthBar.style.width);



    monsterCharachteritics.mStrengthBar.style.width = monsterCharachteritics.mStrength * 10 + "px";

    monsterSDFbarFills.mhFill.innerHTML = `
                       <i class="hp3"> Monster Health Points -${monsterCharachteritics.mHealth}</i>
                       `;
    monsterSDFbarFills.msFill.innerHTML = `
                       <i class="hp3"> Monster Strength Points -${monsterCharachteritics.mStrength}</i>
                       `;
    streDefeHealthBarFills.hFill.innerHTML = `
                       <i class="i">Health Points -${playerCharachteristics.pHealth}</i>
                       `;
    riddleContainer.innerHTML = `
                       <i class="hp3"> You dealt ${overallPlayerDamage} health points worth of damage to your opponent!</i>
                       <i class="hp3"> You received an overall damage of ${overallMonsterDamage} health points by your opponent!</i>
                       `


    if (monsterCharachteritics.mHealth < 0) {
      playerCharachteristics.pHealth += 300;

      healtWidth = 1450;
      playerCharachteristics.pHealthBar.style.width = healtWidth + "px"; //just for style,not accurate-cant reflect length with the actual points sadly
      moveButton.innerHTML += `
                           <button class="Move" onclick="move()"> Throw Dice To Move</button>
                           `;
      divImage.innerHTML = ``;
      monsterHealthDiv.innerHTML = ``;
      attackDiv.innerHTML = ``;
      riddleContainer.innerHTML = ``;
      streDefeHealthBarFills.hFill.innerHTML = `
                       <i class="i">Health Points -${playerCharachteristics.pHealth}</i>
                       `;
    }
    if (playerCharachteristics.pHealth < 0) {
      mainContainer.style.backgroundColor = "red";
      mainContainer.innerHTML = `
                          <i class="hp6"> GAME OVER! YOU DIED!
                          </i>
                          `;
    }
    localStorage.setItem('playerCharachteristics', JSON.stringify(playerCharachteristics));
    localStorage.setItem('monsterCharachteritics', JSON.stringify(monsterCharachteritics));
    localStorage.setItem('monsterBooleanImage', JSON.stringify(booleanGameMechanics));

  }
}


Your code is not complete

Start with this: let objectForMonsterMarkers = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('monsterBooleanImage') || '[]'); which will set the variable to an array if there is no monsterBooleanImage in localStorage

... and then if (monsterBooleanImage === true) { which will not be "true" if it's an array.

Also you never seem to change monsterBooleanImage before storing it. It has a strange name for an Array of something so I think you might be better off if you look at your names and types in your script

You don't seem to be calling .push().   Please see [mcve] and [ask].   There a couple of obvious issues as noted above, but issue in the question doesn't appear to be included in the code.   Please provide a complete snippet that demonstrates the issue - and only the relevant code to reproduce the issue, not your entire code.  Note:  stack-snippets doesn't work with localStorage.   Hover, the issue doesn't appear to be with localStorage - so you need to debug/step-through to find the actual issue.

I haven't checked the entire code, but noticed an invalid syntax in your second if  statement. You have playerCharachteristics = {; here you have an equal sign and then open curly braces, which means you are trying to assign an object to playerCharachteristics. But then without closing the curly braces, so inside of this object, you have monsterCharachteritics = {. This is not valid. First close the curly braces to complete your object, then assign another object to monsterCharachteritics.
I also suggest using an editor (e.g. VS Code) which will highlight the syntax issues.

The syntax error noted above is due to the comment.  The original code (pre-auto-format) had these at the same level, but the closing } is part of the comment.  It's unlikely this is OPs issue as, as it is, it causes syntax errors.  I've edited the code with the assumption it was put on one line for SO

"Start with this: let objectForMonsterMarkers = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('monsterBooleanImage') || '[]'); which will set the variable to an array if there is no monsterBooleanImage in localStorage" I tried that, but it still keeps giving me the same error-objectForMonsterMarker.push is not a function
